# Is this a compiler bug?

Tags: c

My nearly microscopic 8051-based embedded system has a debug serial port, and I wrote a simple serial port output function that was working fine until I made a couple minor tweaks in it to reduce its memory footprint. Then the following line, which WAS working fine (and wasn't part of the changes)...

```
dbg_TxBuf[(dbg_TxBufProduceCount++) & (sizeof(dbg_TxBuf) - 1)] = ch;
```

...stopped working right. The variables `dbg_TxBuf` and `dbg_TxBufProduceCount` are global variables, used only by the output function and the serial port ISR (which was not changed at all):

```
#define DBG_TX_BUFFER_SIZE 16 // MUST be a power-of-2 (this line is actually in a separate file, not that it matters)
volatile uint8_t xdata dbg_TxBuf[DBG_TX_BUFFER_SIZE]; // must be sized by a power-of-2, and MUST BE LESS THAN 256 since the 'count' vars are uint8
volatile uint8_t xdata dbg_TxBufProduceCount; // akin to a 'head' index but more useful since it allows use of every byte in the buf
volatile uint8_t xdata dbg_TxBufConsumeCount; // akin to a 'tail' index but more useful since it allows use of every byte in the buf
```

Specifically what's happening is that the way the compiler is now optimizing the line of code is that `dbg_TxBufProduceCount` is being incremented (in memory) prior to the point that `ch` is written to `dbg_TxBuf`. Then the serial port ISR "occasionally" (actually quite often) sees that `dbg_TxBufConsumeCount != dbg_TxBufProduceCount` and reads `dbg_TxBuf[(dbg_TxBufConsumeCount++) & (sizeof(dbg_TxBuf) - 1)]` prior to the point that the output function writes `ch` to it. Thus I get corrupted output on my serial port.

Here's the 8051 disassembly of that line:

```
935>       dbg_TxBuf[(dbg_TxBufProduceCount++) & (sizeof(dbg_TxBuf) - 1)] = ch;
DC84: 9006D6   MOV   DPTR,#dbg_TxBufProduceCount
DC87: E0       MOVX  A,@DPTR    <--- loads the value in dbg_TxBufProduceCount into the A register
DC88: FE       MOV   R6,A       <--- saves a copy of it in R6
DC89: 04       INC   A          <--- increments it
DC8A: F0       MOVX  @DPTR,A    <--- writes the incremented value 
DC8B: EE       MOV   A,R6       <--- gets the original copy of ProduceCount back in A
DC8C: 7C00     MOV   R4,#00     Begin computing address of dbg_TxBuf[~]...
DC8E: 540F     ANL   A,#0F      <--- A = A & (sizeof(dbg_TxBuf) - 1)
DC90: 24D8     ADD   A,#0D8     <--- A is now the low byte of &dbg_TxBuf[~]
DC92: F582     MOV   DPL,A      <--- put that in DPL
DC94: EC       MOV   A,R4       <--- (an inefficient way of loading the...
DC95: 3406     ADDC  A,#06      <---   ...immediate value 0x06 into A)
DC97: F583     MOV   DPH,A      <--- DPTR now points to dbg_TxBuf[~]
DC99: EF       MOV   A,R7       <--- load 'ch' into A
DC9A: F0       MOVX  @DPTR,A    <--- write 'ch' to *DPTR
```

From a "local" perspective the compiler is treating the post-increment operator correctly, in that it's using the value of `dbg_TxBufProduceCount` prior to the increment in the computation of the index into `dbg_TxBuf`, but from a "global" perspective it seems to me that it's not handling the sequence of events properly, especially since I declared both `dbg_TxBuf[]` and `dbg_TxBufProduceCount` as `volatile`. Shouldn't the compiler be writing the incremented value of `dbg_TxBufProduceCount` to memory ***after*** it writes `ch` to memory?

BTW I'm using the Keil 8051 C compiler, v7.10. I don't know when v7.10 was released, but it appears that our support for the compiler ended in May 2005.

Comment: Where is the [mcve]? And the compiler is likely strictly implementing the abstract machine. You might want to read what the `volatile` qualifier can do for you.

Comment: Too much hand-waving. Looking at the C code is much more helpful than the assembly.

Comment: @Olaf - I've definitely got the 'minimal' part. Supplying the 'complete' part would be a bit lengthy if I included everything including the ISR, so in lieu of that I included the assembly in case anyone wanted more detail. Really the crux of the issue is contained entirely in my "Specifically what's happening..." paragraph and the "From a 'local' perspective..." paragraph near the end. The rest is just details that shouldn't be too important.

Comment: @phonetagger: As much as I will tell is that this is not a compiler bug. Somethimes it is better to not put all into one statement.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Since I was concerned that this was a compiler bug (which it apparently isn't, per David Schwartz's answer), it seems to me that the assembly code would be a fairly critical piece of information for deciding whether there's a compiler bug or not. I think the information in my question was very carefully and reasonably picked to address the question, without providing a lot of unnecessary fluff. I don't think I've done any hand-waving here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't the compiler be writing the incremented value of dbg_TxBufProduceCount to memory after it writes ch to memory?

No. There's no reason it should. Nothing imposes any ordering on the operations that take place inside a single statement. This is a single statement that writes to two volatile variables -- it can write to them in either order. Conceptually, it's no different from:

```
i = a++ + b++;
```

Even if `a` and `b` are volatile, the compiler is free to generate code to write to them in either order. The order of evaluation of parts of a single statement, and the order in which side-effects of that instruction are made visible, is unspecified.